# Removing rows which contain character(0)

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
> head(Companys_)
                           CompanyName Filing FilingDate             Ticker
1 10X Capital Venture Acquisition Corp    S-1 2020-09-25 VCVC, VCVCU, VCVCW
2         2020 ChinaCap Acquirco, Inc.    S-1 2007-04-20                   
3         26 Capital Acquisition Corp.    S-1 2020-12-23 ADER, ADERU, ADERW
4               5:01 Acquisition Corp.    S-1 2020-09-25               FVAM
5            5G Edge Acquisition Corp.    S-1 2021-03-30                   
6              7GC & Co. Holdings Inc.    S-1 2020-12-07  VII, VIIAU, VIIAW
```

How should I remove the rows with no value for the Ticker?

The blanks show up as character(0) when you view the data frame.

Comment: What do you mean by “The blanks show up as character(0) when you view the data frame.”? *How* are you viewing the data set? What’s the type of `TIcker` (`class(Companys_$Ticker)`)?

Comment: @r2evans is right. But just in case this is a list column, you can do: `Companys_ <- Companys_[lengths(Companys_$Ticker) > 0, ]` to remove the empty rows.

Comment: By view I mean `View(Companys_)`. I only showed the top rows here because there are a few hundred rows. And yes it is a list column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a distinct difference between `character(0)` and `""` (0-length string). In R, the `length` of a `character` vector is the number of elements in the vector, regardless of how many (if any) characters are in each string element; the number of characters are found using `nchar`, which returns the number of characters, or `nzchar` which is a faster boolean function which is effectively (but *much* faster than) `nchar(.) > 0`.

To have truly `character(0)` in a frame is certainly possible, but it would require list-columns, which is not a common occurrence in base R applications.

If it is just 0-length strings, then you can use `nzchar`:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Filing = c("S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-1"), FilingDate = c("2020-09-25", "2007-04-20", "2020-12-23", "2020-09-25", "2021-03-30", "2020-12-07"), Ticker = c("VCVC, VCVCU, VCVCW", "", "ADER, ADERU, ADERW", "FVAM", "", "VII, VIIAU, VIIAW")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Filing    : chr  "S-1" "S-1" "S-1" "S-1" ...
#  $ FilingDate: chr  "2020-09-25" "2007-04-20" "2020-12-23" "2020-09-25" ...
#  $ Ticker    : chr  "VCVC, VCVCU, VCVCW" "" "ADER, ADERU, ADERW" "FVAM" ...

dat[nzchar(dat$Ticker),]
#   Filing FilingDate             Ticker
# 1    S-1 2020-09-25 VCVC, VCVCU, VCVCW
# 3    S-1 2020-12-23 ADER, ADERU, ADERW
# 4    S-1 2020-09-25               FVAM
# 6    S-1 2020-12-07  VII, VIIAU, VIIAW
```

If, however, you actually have list-columns (and therefore you may have `character(0)`), then here is some sample data and the fix:

```r
dat <- structure(list(Filing = c("S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-1", "S-1"), FilingDate = c("2020-09-25", "2007-04-20", "2020-12-23", "2020-09-25", "2021-03-30", "2020-12-07"), Ticker = list(c("VCVC", "VCVCU", "VCVCW"), character(0), c("ADER", "ADERU", "ADERW"),     "FVAM", character(0), c("VII", "VIIAU", "VIIAW"))), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Filing    : chr  "S-1" "S-1" "S-1" "S-1" ...
#  $ FilingDate: chr  "2020-09-25" "2007-04-20" "2020-12-23" "2020-09-25" ...
#  $ Ticker    :List of 6
#   ..$ : chr  "VCVC" "VCVCU" "VCVCW"
#   ..$ : chr 
#   ..$ : chr  "ADER" "ADERU" "ADERW"
#   ..$ : chr "FVAM"
#   ..$ : chr 
#   ..$ : chr  "VII" "VIIAU" "VIIAW"

dat[lengths(dat$Ticker) > 0,]
#   Filing FilingDate             Ticker
# 1    S-1 2020-09-25 VCVC, VCVCU, VCVCW
# 3    S-1 2020-12-23 ADER, ADERU, ADERW
# 4    S-1 2020-09-25               FVAM
# 6    S-1 2020-12-07  VII, VIIAU, VIIAW
```

Comment: You're right, the problem was that the Ticker column was a list column. Thanks for your fix!